# Filtering a div out with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I'm trying to filter out a div and get the contents of the div:

```
newData = $(data).filter($("#content")).html();
```

I keep getting [object Object] or null. fed up with trying, so yep.

what im trying to accomplish:

```
$.get('/load.php?url='+url, function(data,textStatus, xhr)
{
newdata = $(data).filter("#this").html();
$("#content").html(newdata);
}
```

Comment: can you show the contents (or useful partial contents) of data?

Comment: The contents of the data is just what I recieve when i do the $.get. I can assure you that's already working. I had it working up until I added this the filtering.

Comment: the new data results with nothing. the old data gives the page i requested.

Comment: Show the value of the `data` that is not filtered then, please.

Comment: -sigh- forgive me for just having it alert/screenshotting but here ya go: http://i.imgur.com/1PzJW.png Also, in the example code i changed it from what I was actually using. I mean I changed basic info just to make it easier to read i guess lol.

Comment: Ok is there an element with the id `this` otherwise  `('#this')` won't be found.

Comment: Like I said it's example code (made it simpler) compared to the data which is live. What i am trying to load (which is "profile-content-lol") is in the loaded data, just didn't fit inside the alert box.

Comment: @Jake Instead of alerting, you could log to console, and copy & paste for better readability.

Comment: Is there an element with the id `this` in the data? You're asking jQuery to turn a string into an HTML object then find an element with the ID `this` and put its contents into the element on your page with the id `contents` e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/2ETWs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), `.filter()` accepts a string, not a selector, so use:

```
newData = $(data).filter("#content").html();
```

Comment: This is still resulting in "null"

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to do something like

```
<div id="foo">
    A quick brown fox
    <div id="bar">
        jumps over a lazy dog!
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script

```
console.log($("#foo").clone().children().remove().end().text());
```

REF: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Comment: it was the term "filter out" wasn't it.

Comment: Filter out as in get the data out of the rest of it. I'm working on a dynamic paging script that needs this

Comment: @Jake can you explain your question with some example markup.

Comment: "get the data out of the rest of it" - get as is retrieve or "get the data out" as in remove?

Comment: retrieve the data, sorry i'm tired and not articulating the best. I added an example

Comment: @Jake Include an example html output too, maybe?

Comment: what the `data` looks like?  i mean the html

Answer (score 0):

Only use filter if it is a top level element (siblings) of the collection (That is unless you are filtering with special requirements using function()).. You need to use .find() instead to find the element if it isn't

```
newdata = $(data).find("#this").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you can try, but this will append rather then replacing so if the content div is already empty then you can use this...

```
$(data).filter($("#this")).appendTo($('#content'));
```

or you have to use replaceWith() method..